# Aggregation query from transaction table

Tags: postgresql

I have came across a requirement where I need to weekly aggregate from transaction table for reporting.
I have one Fact table which contains the product quantity and in transfer quantity and I have date dimension which has date key with week key mapping .

**FCT_PROD_TBL:**

```
DT_KEY      PRD_KEY     LOC_KEY SOH_QTY TSF_IN_QTY
20161113    20012       30034       0       2
20161114    20012       30034       0       1
20161115    20012       30034       3       0
20161118    20012       30034       3       1
20161119    20012       30034       4       0
20161214    20012       30034       2       0
20161215    20012       30034       0       0
```

**DIM_DT:**

```
DT_KEY      TRD_WK_KEY
20161113    20161114
20161114    20161114
20161115    20161121
20161116    20161121
20161117    20161121
20161118    20161121
20161119    20161121
20161120    20161121
20161121    20161121
20161122    20161130
20161123    20161130
20161124    20161130
20161125    20161130
20161126    20161130
20161127    20161130
20161128    20161130
20161129    20161130
20161130    20161130
20161201    20161207
20161202    20161207
20161203    20161207
20161204    20161207
20161205    20161207
20161206    20161207
20161207    20161207
20161208    20161214
20161209    20161214
20161210    20161214
20161211    20161214
20161212    20161214
20161213    20161214
20161214    20161214
20161215    20161221
20161216    20161221
20161217    20161221
20161218    20161221
20161219    20161221
20161220    20161221
20161221    20161221
20161222    20161231
20161223    20161231
20161224    20161231
20161225    20161231
20161226    20161231
20161227    20161231
20161228    20161231
20161229    20161231
20161230    20161231
20161231    20161231
```

Output required:

```
TRD_WK_KEY  PRD_KEY     LOC_KEY SOH_QTY TSF_IN_QTY
20161114    20012       30034       0       3
20161121    20012       30034       4       1
20161130    20012       30034       4       0
20161207    20012       30034       4       0
20161214    20012       30034       2       0
20161221    20012       30034       0       0
20161231    20012       30034       0       0
```

So far I have tried to use left outer join not able to achieve the desired output . If no transaction is happen for any week then it should copy the previous latest weekly aggregate value .Any help or hints to get the desired output .

*SOH_QTY logic :*
The SOH_QTY is the latest available for the date . For example 20161114 ,20161115,2016118,20161119 the SOH_QTY is 0,3,3,4 so the TRD_WK_KEY which contains the mentioned dates should contain the last SOH_QTY ie 4

Comment: Your `SOH_QTY ` looks incorrect.

Comment: Are there more than one PRD_KEY , LOC_KEY?

Comment: @GurV The SOH_QTY is the latest available for the date . For example `20161114 ,20161115,2016118,20161119` the `SOH_QTY` is `0,3,3,4` so the `TRD_WK_KEY` which contains the mentioned dates should contain the last `SOH_QTY` ie `4`

Comment: @McNets there will be more than one PRD_KEY , LOC_KEY

Comment: @ciprian - Still doesnt explain why 20161130, 20161207 has 4 in soh_qty

Comment: and why 1130 and 1207 has soh_qty = 4 then?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected value in soh_qty looks incorrect to me.

For this, you can use FIRST_VALUE window function like this:

```
select
    t.trd_wk_key,
    first_value(prd_key) over (partition by grp order by trd_wk_key) prd_key,
    first_value(loc_key) over (partition by grp order by trd_wk_key) loc_key,
    soh_qty,
    tsf_in_qty
from (
    select 
        d.trd_wk_key,
        max(f.prd_key) prd_key,
        max(f.loc_key) loc_key,
        coalesce(sum(f.soh_qty),0) soh_qty,
        coalesce(sum(f.tsf_in_qty),0) tsf_in_qty,
        sum(case when max(f.prd_key) is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by trd_wk_key) grp
    from DIM_DT d
    left join FCT_PROD_TBL f
    on d.dt_key = f.dt_key
    group by d.trd_wk_key
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated the SOH_QTY logic it should calculate the latest available SOH_QTY for the week

Answer (score 0):

The CTE function, generates a series of all weeks between MIN and MAX date from `FCT_PROD_TBL` table, cross join all `PRD_KEY`, `LOC_KEY`. (Just in case your table have more than one `PRD_KEY, LOC_KEY`)

The second part calculates SUM of `SOH_QTY` and `TSF_IN_QTY` and group it by `TRD_WK_KEY, PRD_KEY, LOC_KEY`.

```
WITH WEEKS AS
(
    SELECT DIM_DT.DT_KEY, DIM_DT.TRD_WK_KEY, PRD_KEY, LOC_KEY
    FROM DIM_DT
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PRD_KEY, LOC_KEY FROM FCT_PROD_TBL) A
    WHERE DIM_DT.DT_KEY >= (SELECT MIN(DT_KEY) FROM FCT_PROD_TBL)
          AND DIM_DT.DT_KEY <= (SELECT MAX(DT_KEY) FROM FCT_PROD_TBL)
)    
SELECT WEEKS.TRD_WK_KEY, WEEKS.PRD_KEY, WEEKS.LOC_KEY,
       COALESCE(SUM(SOH_QTY),0,0) AS SOH_QTY,
       COALESCE(SUM(TSF_IN_QTY),0,0) AS TSF_IN_QTY
FROM WEEKS
     LEFT JOIN FCT_PROD_TBL ON FCT_PROD_TBL.DT_KEY = WEEKS.DT_KEY
GROUP BY WEEKS.TRD_WK_KEY, WEEKS.PRD_KEY, WEEKS.LOC_KEY
ORDER BY WEEKS.TRD_WK_KEY, WEEKS.PRD_KEY, WEEKS.LOC_KEY
;

+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| trd_wk_key | prd_key | loc_key | soh_qty | tsf_in_qty |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161114   | 20012   | 30034   | 0       | 3          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161121   | 20012   | 30034   | 10      | 1          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161130   | 20012   | 30034   | 0       | 0          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161207   | 20012   | 30034   | 0       | 0          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161214   | 20012   | 30034   | 2       | 0          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 20161221   | 20012   | 30034   | 0       | 0          |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

BTW, this values:

```
20161115    20012       30034       3       0
20161118    20012       30034       3       1
20161119    20012       30034       4       0
```

belongs to week  `20161121`

Comment: Calculation for SOH_QTY is based on the latest available soh_qty .20161119 date contains the lastest soh_qty for the week 20161121.